# How do you replace files with other files in python

Tags: python, file

is there a way to replace a file with another file

```
file.replace("png1.png", "png2.png")
```

something like that

Comment: Replace a file or rename a file?

Comment: replace, like for example lets say i have cat.png and dog.png and i want dog.png to put dog.png's contents into cat.png

Comment: What is your O.S.? The files in same directory? You need specify better.

Comment: windows 10 and yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Shutil module.

the method shutil.copy() in Python is used to copy the content of source file to
destination file or directory.

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('png1.png', 'png2.png') #copy src to dst
```